# Vertical align two column divs in Bootstrap3 responsive grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to vertical align (either top align or middle align) the video in the right-hand column and the text in the left-hand column.  Given the code below, how would I do that?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1>Heading<br>Text</h1>
          <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ham hock cow swine meatball salami short loin. Fatback boudin sausage ham. Meatloaf pork chop corned beef, andouille t-bone pancetta flank. Drumstick meatloaf pancetta bresaola, turducken biltong jowl prosciutto ground round kevin venison beef ribs shoulder chuck ham.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <iframe src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/huifu25cy3?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="440" height="248"></iframe><script src="http://fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise is to do it with jQuery, here's one simple solution, sorry I had to add a few ID's on your existing code

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <div class="row" id="some_id">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Heading<br>Text</h1>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ham hock cow swine meatball salami short loin. Fatback boudin sausage ham. Meatloaf pork chop corned beef, andouille t-bone pancetta flank. Drumstick meatloaf pancetta bresaola, turducken biltong jowl prosciutto ground round kevin venison beef ribs shoulder chuck ham.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#">Submit</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <iframe id="iframe_id" src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/huifu25cy3?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="440" height="248"></iframe>
      <script src="http://fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the jQuery script:

```
// Vertical center
function vericalCenter() { 
if ($('.container').width() > 969) {
 $('#iframe_id').css({
     "margin-top": ((($('#some_id').height() - $('#iframe_id').outerHeight()) / 2) + $('#some_id').scrollTop() + "px")
    });
  };
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 vericalCenter();               
});

$(window).resize(function(){        
 vericalCenter();                   
});
```

here's the demo, just remember to resize the result frame to be wider than 970px in order to see the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/CzNUQ/